# How to load local 3d image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

I'm trying to load view of 3D image in javascript. I've already tried libraries like three.js or marzipano, but I get cors errors like:

> Access to image at 'file:///C:/Users/myimage.jpg' from origin 'null'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
> supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
> chrome-untrusted, https.

My question is: is it possible to load 3D image from my local filesystem without creating server?

Comment: Why not create a server? It's as easy as `python -m http.server`. There's good security reasons why JS can't access your local FS and it makes much more sense to run a server instead of trying to circumvent the restrictions. The fact that the image is 3d is irrelevant here.

Comment: I have to create .zip which contains all files and project should work without server. I know it's easy to create, but that's just the requirement I've got.

Comment: That requirement is absolutely impossible to fulfill. Who is asking you to do this? Browsers do not have access to your hard-drive to protect users from malicious requests. Otherwise someone could just snoop all over your hard-drive by looking into folders like: `file:///C:/Users/Default/Documents/` The error message gives you the only possible protocols: `http, https, data, chrome-`. as you can see the `file` protocol is not allowed. This is why Three.js has a section on how to run things locally: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Got, it, but if I want to load audio files it is possible with `new Audio('./assets/file.mp3')`, same for video or image. So is there similar option for 3d image?